# Why Pandas does not recognize X values in a Chart as Distinct?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have a DataFrame with the following Columns:

- **countriesAndTerritories** = Name of the Countries (Only contains Portugal and Spain)
- **cases** = Number of Covid Cases

This is how the DataFrame looks like:
[image]

We have 1 row per "dateRep".

I tried to create a BarChart with the following code:

```
 df.plot.bar(x="countriesAndTerritories", y="cases", rot=70,
 title="Number of Covid cases per Country")
```

The result is the following:
[image]

As you can see, instead of having the total number of cases per Country (Portugal and Spain), i have multiple values in the X axis.

I've tried to investigate a little, but the examples i've found were with a inline df. So, if someone can help me, i apreciate.

PS: I'm used to QlikSense, and what i'm trying to achieve, would be something along these lines:
[image: QlikSense Example]

Comment: `df.groupby('countriesAndTerritories')['cases'].sum().plot.bar()` ?

Comment: This is absolutely correct. I'll try to understand the code before applying it. Thank you for the help!